# Fourier Transform of Cosine

Tags: fourier-transform

I want to calculate the Fourier Transform of a cosine signal that is$\;\mathfrak{F}\{ cos(\frac{7\pi}{2}t)\}\:?$
In some sources it is given as (1)
$\;\mathfrak{F}\{ cos(w_0t)\}\:=\:\pi [\delta(w-w_0)+\delta(w+w_0)]$
Other sources have (2)
$\;\mathfrak{F}_t[ cos(2\pi k_0t)](k)\:=\:\frac{1}{2} [\delta(k-k_0)+\delta(k+k_0)]$
(1) is from the Signals&Systems book by Oppenheim, (2) is from [Wolfram FourierTransformCosine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformCosine.html). How can these two representations be equivalent? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Each source usually gives a definition of the Fourier transform form used. From (1) and (2) the resulting answers are equivalent. What is also clear is the way the Fourier transform is defined is different for each of (1) and (2)'s sources.

Comment: See also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Units_and_duality

Comment: There isn't one single definition of the Fourier transform, unfortunately. There's a different normalization constant and frequency-scaling constant depending on who you're asking

Comment: @Leucippus I just can't understand how can results be equivalent although they have different scaling factors in delta functions.